# Scala: Accessing/casting entries from Map[String, Any] or better alternative

Tags: scala, dictionary, casting, attributes, any

With pattern matching I am extracting attributes from an AST and saving them in a Map[String, Any], because they can be Strings, Integers, Lists etc. Now I want to use the attributes in a case class. For getting the elements I wrote this method:

```
def getAttr(attr: Map[String, Any], key : String):Any = {
   val optElem = attr.get(key) match {
     case Some(elem) => elem
     case _ => throw new Exception("Required Attribute " + key + " not found")
  }
}
```

Because I always know what type every attribute value is I want to use the value like this:

```
case class Object1(id: String, name: String)

Object1("o1", getAttr(attrMap, "name").asInstanceOf[String])
```

But I get the error "scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to collect and use my attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of getAttr has type Unit since you return result of assignment of value to optElem

To fix:

```
def getAttr(attr: Map[String, Any], key : String):Any = {
  attr.get(key) match {
    case Some(elem) => elem
    case _ => throw new Exception("Required Attribute " + key + " not  found")
  }
}
```

Comment: I hate when I do stupid mistakes like that...and because of the Any typing I didn't figure it out...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As addition to @Nyavro's absolutely correct answer: to avoid calling `asInstanceOf` every time you use `getAttr`, you can add type parameter to it:

```
def getAttr[R](attr: Map[String, Any], key: String): R = {
   val optElem = attr.get(key) match {
     case Some(elem) => elem
     case _ => throw new Exception("Required Attribute " + key + " not found")
   }
   optElem.asInstanceOf[R]
}
```

And then just

```
Object1("o1", getAttr(attrMap, "name"))
```